# Doesn't Yandex care about canonical link tags?

Tags: html, search-engine, google-search, canonical-link

In email newsletters and in Twitter I Share my homepage link like this:
http://www.example.com/?utm_source=email&utm_campaign=june

To not to create duplicate content I put "link canonical" tag into my webpages.
Google fixes it well. Google sends the "utm tagged" results to the last pages of SERP or doesn't show them.

But Yandex shows "utm tagged" results even in first pages of SERPs. And crawls that pages over and over. So doesn't Yandex take "canonical" into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site page addresses contain dynamic parameters that do not affect the content (e.g. identifiers of sessions, users, referrers etc.), you can describe them using the ['Clean-param' directive](http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/?id=1113851#1113859).

To exclude `http://www.example.com/?utm_source=email&utm_campaign=june` try to add following lines in `robots.txt`

```
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow:
Clean-param: utm_source&utm_campaign /
```

For more information look into the [documentation](http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/?id=1113851#1113859).

Comment: That's simple good solution! I was using canonical tag but adding this became a bonus.